# django: assigning foreign key before target model is saved

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Assume `A` and `B` are django Models, where `A` has a foreign key field to `B`:

```
a = A()
b = B()
a.my_b = b
b.save()
a.save()
```

Surprisingly `a` is saved with `null` in the `my_b` foreign key field. If you check `a.my_b` before or after the saves it *does* refer to the `b` instance, however it seems that django evaluates the foreign key id itself upon `a.my_b = b` assignment and not upon `a.save()`. In complex systems and flows it may be hard to change the order of commands, so simply saving `b` before assigning it to `a` could be impractical...

Adding the incredible statement `a.my_b=a.my_b` between the save commands works, but seems to me a horrid workaround.

**Is there a way to configure django to re-evaluate foreign keys upon saving model instances?**

Is there a different approach that might solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a Django ticket that describes this issue, [#8892](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8892).

In the meantime, there's no configuration setting that changes the behaviour. You'll have to change the order of your save and assignment operations, or do the extra assignment.

Comment: This bit me when I tried to dynamically create model instances from nested JSON data. In my case I couldn't save the instances before all fields were handled (which would result in the related instances being created), so I couldn't save before the assignment. Instead I built a list of functions to be called when the instances were all wired up. In addition to each instance's save method I added a `partial(setattr, name, value)` so the dodgy assignments were queued until the related instance had been saved. Sadly it doesn't look like #8892 will ever be fixed but at least they'll add an error.

Comment: @pluma could you expand on your solution? I am dealing with the same problem.